# Why does my find cmd yield results when executed manually but not from script

Tags: shell

I´m executing this command from commandline

```
find -L /lorem/ipsum/dolor/ /lorem/ipsum1/dolor/ /lorem3/ipsum/dolor/  -regex '.*[0-9]_[0-9].*log.*?' -mtime +14 -type f | wc -l
```

and it yields

70

But when I run it in script it doesn´t.
The speciality is, that in script I´m passing the path as GLOB value, and find resolves it for me.
That is

```
CLEANUPFOLDER="/lorem/**/dolor/"
```

command in script:

```
find -L $CLEANUPFOLDER -mtime +14 -type f | wc -l
```

I tried to copy the resolved find in new script and it worked

Comment: In your script, just above the `find -L...` line, add the line `shopt -s globstar`.  Then, run the script and tell us if it works.

Comment: ```
./cleanup_nas_shares.sh: line 111: shopt: globstar: invalid shell option name
```
I did an 
```
set -f instead, but I didn´t work either
```

Comment: Since the code has `lorem/**/dolor/`  (2 stars in a row), it requires that `globstar` be set.  Under bash, `shopt -s globstar` should work.  Some follow-up questions:  What is the output of `bash --version`?  What is your script's shebang (`#!`) line?  How are you invoking your script?

Answer (score 0):

what I forgot to mention was, that I´m passing then

> /lorem/ipsum/dolor/ /lorem/ipsum1/dolor/ /lorem3/ipsum/dolor/  -regex
>   '.*[0-9]_[0-9].*log.*?'

as variable to the command

like

> VAR1="/lorem/ipsum/dolor/ /lorem/ipsum1/dolor/ /lorem3/ipsum/dolor/ 
>   -regex '.*[0-9]_[0-9].*log.*?'"
>
> find $VAR1 .....

the problem now was also, that find interpreted the space between "...or/" and  "..-rege" not as seperator between parameters, but somewhow as part of the folder ...
So the find went awry and the error msg was hidden..

Now I did it like that

> bash -c"find ....." and it worked at once ....

Thanks guys, and sorry for the bad explaination of things :-(